# How to call five services in activity one by one using intent service

Tags: android

I have working with the application which requires to call 5 to 10 services .I have to call the service one by one .After completion of the first service ,i need to call second service this is the work flow.I have used the intent service for my purpose.How to achieve this in efficient way.

This the mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Intent service_1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Service1.class);
        startService(service_1);
        Intent service_2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Service2.class);
        startService(service_2);
        Intent service_3=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Service3.class);
        startService(service_3);

    }

}
```

1st service

```
 public class Service1  extends IntentService{

    public Service1() {
        super("serviceone");
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            Log.e("service1","service1::............."+i);
        }

    }
}
```

2nd service

```
 public class Service2 extends IntentService {

    public Service2() {
        super("service2");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            Log.e("service2", "service::2*****************" + i);
        }

    }
}
```

3rd service

```
 public class Service3 extends IntentService{

    public Service3() {
        super("service3");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            Log.e("service3", "service::3####################" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

iam getting log

```
   ce1: service1::.............323
08-18 16:12:14.441 6614-6640/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.............324
08-18 16:12:14.441 6614-6640/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.............325
08-18 16:12:14.441 6614-6640/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.............326
08-18 16:12:14.441 6614-6640/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.............327
08-18 16:12:14.441 6614-6640/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.............328
08-18 16:12:14.441 6614-6640/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.............329
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************0
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************1
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************2
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************3
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************4
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************5
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************6
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************7
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************8
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************9
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************10
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************11
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************12
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************13
08-18 16:12:14.453 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************14
08-18 16:12:14.454 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************15
08-18 16:12:14.454 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************16
08-18 16:12:14.454 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************17
08-18 16:12:14.454 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************18
08-18 16:12:14.454 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************19
08-18 16:12:14.454 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************20
08-18 16:12:14.454 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************21
08-18 16:12:14.454 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************22
08-18 16:12:14.454 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************23
08-18 16:12:14.454 6614-6641/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************24
08-18 16:12:14.457 6614-6640/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.............330
08-18 16:12:14.457 6614-6640/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.............331
08-18 16:12:14.457 6614-6640/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.............332
```

2nd approach

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Intent service_2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Service2.class);
       // startService(service_2);
        //Intent service_3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Service3.class);
       // startService(service_3);




        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent1, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),10000,
                pendingIntent);

    }

}
```

Broadcast receiver

```
  public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //get and send location information

        Intent service_1 = new Intent(context, Service1.class);
        context.startService(service_1);

        Intent service_2 = new Intent(context, Service2.class);
        context.startService(service_2);

    }
}
```

service class

```
public class Service1  extends IntentService{

    public Service1() {
        super("serviceone");
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        forloopMethod();


    }


    private void forloopMethod()

    {
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        {
            Log.e("service1","service1::.serviceone............"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

error log

```
 ice E/service1: service1::.serviceone............9837
08-18 17:47:39.916 12517-21515/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.serviceone............9838
08-18 17:47:39.916 12517-21515/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.serviceone............9839
08-18 17:47:39.916 12517-21515/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.serviceone............9840
08-18 17:47:39.916 12517-21515/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service1: service1::.serviceone............9841
08-18 17:47:39.936 12517-21516/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************9751
08-18 17:47:39.936 12517-21516/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************9752
08-18 17:47:39.936 12517-21516/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************9753
08-18 17:47:39.936 12517-21516/homedashboard.egrove.com.multipleservice E/service2: service::2*****************9754
```

Same getting i would like to make first service call .After first service completed and then make second service call.This is need..help me

Comment: Why don't you try with `BroadcastReceiver`? After every `service` started it will send a message to a `BroadcastReceiver` registered on your `Activity`. Depends on that message take a decision that which service you want to start now.

Comment: please see the code below

Comment: Which code you mean? Didn't find any code below :(

Comment: in the second approach. see above i have edit the code

Comment: edited 14 mins ago

Comment: In here your `AlarmReceiver` starting all services one by one. Not waiting for one to finish before starting another one. My idea is: register a receiver (`MessageReceiver`) in your `Activity` which will used to receive message from all services. After getting a message start another service depends on your requirement. Now in every service send broadcast message to your `MessageReceiver` when it is going to finish. Now start your first service from your activity it will automatically create a queue.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a broadcast when a service finishes to let the activity know.

Sample implementation:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate() {
        ...
        mMyReceiver = new MyReceiver(this);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, new IntentFilter(SERVICE_FINISHED_ACTION));
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mMyReceiver != null) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMyReceiver);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void launchServiceTwo() {
        Intent service2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Service2.class);
        startService(service2);
    }

    ...

    private static class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mWeakActivity;

        public MyReceiver(@NonNull MainActivity activity) {
            mWeakActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            MainActivity listener = mWeakActivity.get();
            if (listener != null && bundle != null) {
                String serviceFinishedExtra = bundle.getString(SERVICE_FINISHED_EXTRA);
                if ("Service1".equalsIgnoreCase(serviceFinishedExtra)) {
                    launchServiceTwo();
                } else if ("Service2".equalsIgnoreCase(serviceFinishedExtra)) {
                    launchServiceThree();
                } else if ...
            }
        }

    }
}

public class Service1 extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ...
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(SERVICE_FINISHED_ACTION);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(SERVICE_FINISHED_EXTRA, "Service1");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent1, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),10000,
                pendingIntent);

Comment: i have used the code to call that service every 10 second..How can i integrate this code in your code?

Comment: Please, try to explain better what you are trying to achieve. The original question was how to call various services sequentially. Now you are stating that you are using an alarm manager. Why is that? Are you trying to run the services sequentially and also each certain amount of time repeatedly?

Comment: i have to achieve both :::::: to run the services sequentially and also each certain amount of time repeatedly